# Remove border-right like box-shadow

Tags: css

Is it possible to remove the border-right 'like' in the box of the icon? I created the border using the box-shadow property.

CSS:

```
box-shadow: rgb(255, 255, 255) 0px 0px 0px 0px, rgb(229, 231, 235) 0px 0px 0px 1px,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 0px 1px 2px 0px;
```

[image]

Comment: Need more context. What's the html?

Comment: I already fixed it.

Comment: Then you should update your question with more details, and put in your own answer to help others.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would probably be to switch to using a border made with... well, a border.  You could recreate the look you have here with borders and set border-right-style to "hidden" as needed.

But, assuming you have your own reasons for using box-shadow instead: it's probably the shadow coming through in the empty spaces between elements that is your problem.  You could try something like removing the right margins on the icons or the left margins of everything next to them so that there's no gaps.

I'm kind of struggling to understand the wording of this question, so apologies if these aren't what you're looking for.

Comment: When I remove the margins, the 'border' between the text and the icon becomes thicker

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks for your help!